# InappBrowser opening Paypal in Normal browser after installing Crosswalk in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, braintree, inappbrowser, crosswalk

I am using Braintree payments in my Ionic app. Before installing Crosswalk, it was working fine.

After installing Crosswalk, whenever I click on Paypal button in Dropin page, InappBrowser is trying to open the link in Normal External Browser instead of Webview. Any suggestions how to make Paypal open in Webview only.

I am testing this on Android device. I have cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview and cordova-plugin-inappbrowser installed and below is my system info.

- Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
- Ionic Framework Version: 1.1.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.15
- Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.2
- ios-deploy version: 1.8.6
- ios-sim version: 5.0.8
- Node Version: v0.12.4
- Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The short answer to this is that [Braintree does not support Cordova apps](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/browser-support#webviews). Even if you found a solution to this specific issue, there are enough moving pieces in the compilation that Braintree wouldn't be able to support your integration if/when you went into production.

Answer (score 0):

Things have moved on since [@Raymond Berg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200217/raymond-berg)'s answer:

With the advent of Braintree's own PopupBridge, which provides emulated popup behaviour for [Android](https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-android) and [iOS](https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-ios) Webviews, it's now possible to make webpages containing Braintree's JS SDK (and therefore Web Drop-in) work correctly in native Android and iOS Webviews.

Therefore I've just published [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge), which adds support for Braintree's PopupBridge functionality to Cordova's InappBrowser. This makes it possible to support Braintree-powered PayPal payments within the context of the InappBrowser element of Cordova-based Android and iOS apps.